# Simple fadein not running smooth

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a beginner in jQuery and JS and I wanted to make a simple fade in animation using the following code. Unfortunately the code is not running smooth, and despite reading up all the basics (at least I suppose so) I cannot get it to run smoothly. Can anyone point me in the correct direction on how to make a smooth fade in animation?

All my elements are visible in the beginning. I don't want to start with hidden elements as this could result in problems in my UI if there is no JS enabled.

Thank you.

```
$(function () {
    $("#center_block").animate(
        {
            opacity: 0,
        }, 0, function () {
            $("#center_block").animate({
                opacity: 1,
            }, 250);
        });
});
```

Comment: How would you fade in something that is already visible?

Comment: Please add your relevant HTML and CSS to your question.

Comment: Personally, I'd use CSS transitions instead of Javascript for something this simple. Take advantage of hardware acceleration, they are much smoother and simpler to code.

Comment: @Bricky I think he made it invisiable by using `opacity:0` first. But he didn't use `display:none`.

Comment: @RobertWade CSS transitions don't work on load, even when you apply a class with javascript on load. It would be best to use CSS3 animations to reproduce this example.

Comment: In my code I was hiding it with the first animation, but that was not smooth. I settled on CSS now. I don't have to use JS necessarily. The current code was a remnant of much more complicated code that never ended up running properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a slow processor on your computer or if you are viewing javascript animations a mobile device the processor might not be able to cope with the animation. If you use CSS3 animations then the inbuilt browsers hardware acceleration is used, which is a lot more efficient.

All I am doing is using CSS3 animation to apply the fade.

```css
@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity:1;
  }
}

#center_block {
  animation: 1s ease-out fadeIn;
}
```

```html
<div id="center_block">Look at me, I'm Mr Center Block</div>
```

Comment: There's no need for a trigger if the animation is supposed to happen automatically. Also, CSS Animations are widely supported now, so the vendor prefixes can all be removed.

Comment: Thank you! Went with this as it was exactly what I tried to achieve.

Comment: @Claude No problem. Scott Marcus' suggestions made it a lot more efficient. Be sure to check Scotts code because they show good examples for different situations you may have in the future.

Answer (score 2):

There really is no need for JavaScript at all here. **[CSS animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations)** can do this more easily with better performance (because they will leverage GPU hardware acceleration):

```css
span { 
 font-size:3em;
 font-weight:bold;
 font-family:Arial;
 border:1px solid grey;
 background-color:aliceblue;
 display:inline-block;
 padding:10px;
 opacity:0;
 
 /* Configure the element to use the animation */
 animation: 3s infinite fade;
}

@keyframes fade {
 0% { opacity:0; }
 50% { opacity:1; }
 100% { opacity:0; }
}
```

```html
<span>Hello</span>
```

Or, if you don't want the animation to be automatic and have some sort of trigger, then just add a CSS class to the object at the right time:

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function(){
  document.querySelector("span").classList.add("animate");
});
```

```css
span { 
 font-size:3em;
 font-weight:bold;
 font-family:Arial;
 border:1px solid grey;
 background-color:aliceblue;
 display:inline-block;
 padding:10px;
 opacity:0;
}

.animate {
 /* Configure the element to use the animation */
 animation: 3s infinite fade;
}

@keyframes fade {
 0% { opacity:0; }
 50% { opacity:1; }
 100% { opacity:0; }
}
```

```html
<button>Click to Start</button>
<span>Hello</span>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, these animations are amazing. I settled for now on

    .fadein {
     opacity:0;
     animation: 250ms fade forwards;
    }

    @keyframes fade {
     0% { opacity:0; }
     100% { opacity:1; }
    }

Comment: @Claude You are welcome. Don't forget to up vote all helpful answers and to mark this one as "the" answer if you feel it best answered your question.

Comment: I'm so sorry, I can just go with one answer and I have chosen the one by WizardCoder as it was spot on. But be assured, your animation has given me great inspiration for my project! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise using CSS animations as much as possible for the smoothest performance. A great library to get you started is [animate.css](https://github.com/daneden/animate.css). To use it, include the css library in your project and use javascript to add predefined classes to your components. In your case:

```
$('#center_block').addClass('animated fadeIn');
```

would fade in the `#center_block` element nicely.

Comment: Thanks! I went with applying the class directly as I always want to run the effect on pageload. animate.css is great. I have it used elsewhere in the project.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to hide the elements incase JS is disabled, then you need to hide them first using JS. Also, you're currently using 250ms, which is incredibly fast, and unlikely to be perceived by users.

```
$(document).on('ready', function(){
    $('#center_block').hide().fadeIn(250);
});
```

If your elements already have `opacity: 0;` for the CSS, then you can add a transition to handle the animation:

```
#center_block{
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all .25s linear;
}
```

Then change the CSS value of opacity whenever the triggering condition is met:

```
$('#center_block').css('opacity','1');
```

Comment: Tried it, unfortunately the div first showed up, then disappeared and then faded in. I want a smooth experience now matter how "bad" the computer. Thank you!

Comment: p.S. I settled for 250ms as it should just be a nice loading effect, but not annoy or "interact" with the user in any way. Google material design recommends no longer time intervals than 250ms on fadeins.